# combine rows with same values and apply a function to get a ratio

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset looks like this

```
time   value
0.1    2
0.1    3
0.2    2
0.2    4
0.2    1
```

I also have a threshold value `threshold = 2.5`

I want to combine the rows with the same time point and calculate the ratio above the threshold and return a table like this:

```
time    value
0.1     0.50
0.2     0.33
```

I have tried to use `data.table` to combine all the rows with same time  points but I am having some trouble to come up a function to calculate ratio at each time point. I know that I could write some `for loop` but I am wondering if there's a more R way to solve this problem.

My thought is something like this:

```
results <- dt[,some_function(value, threshold),by=time]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `mean(value > threshold)` is your `some_function`

Comment: Fyi, grouping by floats is dangerous, since `1. + .2 != .3` etc. http://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/

Comment: Also, shouldn't the second row be `0.2,0.33`

Comment: @Osssan thanks:)  just edited.

Comment: @Gregor Thank you!!

Comment: @Frank I see. I will keep that in mind. Thank you!